# sed in bash to overrewrite to same file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I want to remove the headers of a file and replace its content without headers in the same file.

Example: `file_student`

```
name age
XYS 24
RTF 56
```

The output should be:

```
XYS 24
RTF 56
```

The scenario is that I do not want to create any new file for this change. Can `sed` do this?

I tried:

```
sed 1d /tmp/file_student.txt |
hadoop fs -copyfromLocal /tmp/file_student.txt /tmp/file_student_no_header.txt
```

But that does not work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @anubhava , but I do not want a backup file to be created. In this case it creates a /tmp/file_student.txt.bak file

Comment: `sed -i '1d' /tmp/file_student.txt`

Answer (score 0):

an extract from `sed`'s man page

> `-i[SUFFIX]'`
>   --in-place[=SUFFIX]'
>        This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
>        `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
>        this file rather than to the standard output.(1).
>
> ```
>  This option implies `-s'.
>
>  When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed
>  to the output file's original name.  The extension, if supplied,
>  is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the
>  temporary file, thereby making a backup copy(2)).
>
>  This rule is followed: if the extension doesn't contain a `*',
>  then it is appended to the end of the current filename as a
>  suffix; if the extension does contain one or more `*' characters,
>  then _each_ asterisk is replaced with the current filename.  This
>  allows you to add a prefix to the backup file, instead of (or in
>  addition to) a suffix, or even to place backup copies of the
>  original files into another directory (provided the directory
>  already exists).
>
>  If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten
>  without making a backup.
> ```

so you need to change your sed command to sth like
`sed -i 1d file | whatever`
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `sed`, try `tail` - e.g. you have a file called xxx:

`tail -n +2 xxx > xxx.tmp && mv xxx.tmp xxx`